# How can I clone a Git repository using CLI when connected with SSH?

Tags: git, ssh, private, vscode-remote-ssh

In local machine, I can clone organization private repository. But I can not in SSH.

How can I deal with this?

The github username and email are correct. And the error is related to usr, sock, ...

I tried to get access token but I can not get access token. So I thought there maybe a good way to clone without access token, only with username, email, password. But in SSH, the prompt does not appeared.

Comment: I might be wrong, but i think github removed the option to use username and password for ssh, reading [their ssh faq](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh) however I cannot find that. But all the guides are using ssh-keys, which would be the right way to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this solution will help you.

IN your pc open terminal and Generate the ssh key. To Generate [click here](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/cloud-at-customer/occ-get-started/generate-ssh-key-pair.html)

Then open the public key file cpy it an add it in your github using gui in settings.

Then try cloning with ssh url given by github, I'm Sure it will work.